# OWASP ZAP - jython script documentation

Tags: jython, owasp, zap

I'm SQLi testing a client's web application and i'm using OWASP ZAP for that. As the web page that receives the injected value always redirects the user by a JSON response (HTTP status code is still 200 OK), i'm trying to develop a jython-based script to make the tool issue a request to the json-provided redirection url.

The problem is that ZAP's internal structure documentation is kind of messy... I cannot understand how i'm supposed to reference things in the "Scripts" tab.

I tried the following "Proxy" script:

```
import org.zaproxy.clientapi.gen.Core as core1;

def proxyResponse(msg):
  # Debugging can be done using print like this
  print(core1.version().getName());

  return True;
```

but all i get is a `java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException` error. "Output" tab is empty and i could not find any other information. Does anyone know how to solve this or where can i find some other documentation or jython example script to help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused at what you're trying to do:
org.zaproxy.clientapi.gen.Core is part of the ZAP client API and therefore isnt included in ZAP itself.

Can you start a thread on the ZAP User Group: http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users
Yes, the documentation could be better.
But we do provide user and developer groups which are linked off the ZAP 'Online' menu. If only more people would use them ;)

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: For info DarkLightning started a thread on the ZAP User Group (thanks!): https://groups.google.com/d/msg/zaproxy-users/javC-auDbqI/QagWyAEzRkEJ